# Visual Studio 2022 Community: can't make edit of a custom step take effect, can't find in proj files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

To set the scene: I inherited a VC++ solution from a departed team member.  It has a project with a .i file which I believe happens to be an input file for a utility called swig.  Right clicking on the .i file -->Properties-->Configuration Properties-->Custom Build Tool-->General shows an invocation of swig.exe with the argument "%(FullPath)" (I assume the name of this .i file with a full path).  Upon compilation, swig.exe is correctly invoked, it seems.

After doing Build-->Build Solution, it outputs:

```
6>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(245,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "..\..\swig\MyFile.i" succeeded, but specified output "t:\MyEmployer\MyCodeBase\MyProject\auxiliary\visualstudioprojects\vs2017\_wrap.cxx" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
```

Back on the Properties dialog above, `Outputs` is defined as `$(InputName)_wrap.cxx;%(Outputs)` .  Googling a bit I see `$(InputName)` is no longer supported since VS2015 or so.

**THE PROBLEM:** OK, let's assume this is cruft the earlier engineer should have taken out at some point.  Maybe it allowed VS to verify the command had actually produced the output file.  But it always works, and a failure to produce it would become obvious pretty quickly anyway, so we don't need that check.  **So I delete `$(InputName)_wrap.cxx;` and hit OK, and do a Clean Solution and Build Solution.`

**But the edit seems to have not taken effect.**

I go back and check, and yes, it's gone.  But I still get the above error about _wrap.cxx ...

So I exit and restart... and the **`$(InputName)_wrap.cxx;` is back again!**

So on Linux (which mounts the same file system) I do a find through all files including binary files and don't find `_wrap.cxx` anywhere.  I don't find `swig.exe` anywhere.  **I don't find `$(InputName)` anywhere.**

So the question is: where could this stuff possibly be defined and why can I not delete it?!!?**

Answer (score 0):

OK, I went through the *.vcxproj files very carefully, looking for anything that didn't seem to be related to some feature of VC++ that I knew of.

I found the following mysterious line:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  <Import Project="$(MYCOMPANY_DIR)\$(MSVC_VERSION)\foo.props" Condition="exists('$(MYCOMPANY_DIR)\$(MSVC_VERSION)\foo.props')" />
</ImportGroup>
```

And `$MYCOMPANY_DIR` is two directory levels above my personal project, so my find/grep could not find the commands in question.

And in the file `$(MYCOMPANY_DIR)\$(MSVC_VERSION)\foo.props`, I see:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CustomBuild Include="..\..\swig\$(ProjectName).i">
    <FileType>Document</FileType>
    <Outputs>$(InputName)_wrap.cxx;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
    <Command>%MYCOMPANY_DIR%\third_party\swigwin-3.0.6\swig.exe -c++ -python  -I%MYCOMPANY_DIR%/myproduct/include -I%MYCOMPANY_DIR%/myproduct/swig -I%MYCOMPANY_DIR%/libraries -I../../../third_party/include   -outdir $(OutDir) "%(FullPath)"</Command>
  </CustomBuild>
</ItemGroup>
```

So basically, Visual C++ was showing this `$(InputName)` from this "props" file (whatever that is) as if it was a property of my own project, *and even letting me edit that and apparently tracking that edit albeit not actually using it*.  Changing this "prop" file from the no-longer-supported `$(InputName)` to `$(OutDir)\swig\%(FileName)_wrap.cxx` now has my make proceeding without warning.

Further, I assume VC++ uses its knowledge of the output file name to see that since the output is newer than the input, it doesn't need to be rebuilt, thus speeding the build a bit.